# Cannot save profile while setting up VPN

Tags: 8.1, lumia, vpn

I am trying to set up a VPN on Windows Phone. To do this I installed multiple SSL VPN apps like MobileIron and AnyConnect. When I got to "Settings > VPN > [Add profile]" and fill in the details I cannot save the profile.

[image: Cannot save VPN profile]

When I have filled in all boxes the save button remains grayed out. Why is this? How can I save the VPN profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When connect automatically was turned off, or a valid IP range was selected for which to connect automatically the button was no longer grayed out.